# Why does my array of error messages gets overrwritten?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a simple component where I want to edit my username. I can introduce a total of 3 errors - username too short, username doesnt match regex and username is already taken. I keep my error messages in the state `const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);` After the user types new username I call the following method:

```
const changeUsername = async (newUsername) => {
    setUsername(newUsername);
    setErrors([]);
    await checkNewUername(newUsername);
  };

  const checkNewUername = async (newUsername) => {
    console.log("errors ", errors);
    const usernameRegex = new RegExp("/^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$/");
    if (!usernameRegex.test(newUsername)) {
      setErrors((errors) => [
        ...errors,
        "Username must be alpha numeric characters, underscores and dots.",
      ]);
    }
    if (newUsername.length < 6) {
      setErrors((errors) => [
        ...errors,
        "Username must be at least 6 characters.",
      ]);
    }
    await isUsernameTaken(newUsername);
    console.log("errors ", errors);
  };



     const isUsernameTaken = async (newUsername) => {
      //call to my db
    await usernameRef
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          setErrors((errors) => [...errors, "Username is taken"]);
        } else {
          setErrors((errors) => [...errors, "No new error"]);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
  };
```

When I type "tr a" for a username, I would expect my `errors` piece of state to contain 3 errors. However, what happens in reality is that ther `errors` gets overwritten with the latest error. Here is my console output:

> errors:  Array [] errors:  Array [] errors:  Array [] errors:  Array
> [] errors:  Array [] calling checkNewUername:  tra
>
> errors:  Array [
> "Username must be alpha numeric characters, underscores and dots.", ]
>
> errors:  Array [   "Username must be at least 6 characters.", ]
> isUsernameTaken was called with:  tra  calling checkNewUername:  tra
>
> errors:  Array [   "Username must be alpha numeric characters,
> underscores and dots.", ]
>
> errors:  Array [   "Username must be at
> least 6 characters.", ] isUsernameTaken was called with:  tra errors:
> Array [   "No new error", ]
>
> calling checkNewUername:  tr errors:
> Array [   "Username must be alpha numeric characters, underscores and
> dots.", ] errors:
>
> Array [   "Username must be at least 6
> characters.", ] isUsernameTaken was called with:  tr errors:
>
> Array [ "No new error", ] errors:
>
> Array [   "No new error", ] calling
> checkNewUername:  tra errors:
>
> Array [   "Username must be alpha
> numeric characters, underscores and dots.", ] errors:
>
> Array [ "Username must be at least 6 characters.", ] isUsernameTaken was
> called with:  tra
>
> errors:  Array [   "No new error", ]

And on the screen I see only "No new error"

How do I add new wrrors, instead of overwriting the existing one? I want to display all errors together.

**EDIT**:
This is my console output when I tried with a very short username:

isUsernameTaken was called with:  t
errors:  Array [
"No new error",
"No new error",
"No new error",
"Username must be at least 6 characters.",
]
errors:  Array [
"No new error",
"No new error",
"No new error",
"No new error",
]
errors  Array [
"No new error",
"No new error",
"No new error",
]
errors  Array [
"No new error",
"No new error",
"No new error",
"No new error",
]

Comment: Well what does `setErrors()` do?

Comment: it is part of the state: const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

Comment: @Pointy thats how I update the state; I keep the error messages as an array. If this is not the correct way, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the lambda inside the `setErrors` call, but just provide a simple value.
The `errors` should be available for you to grab from the outer scope and not as a lambda parameter.

So instead of

```js
setErrors((errors) => [
  ...errors,
  "Username must be alpha numeric characters, underscores and dots.",
]);
```

you should simply do:

```js
setErrors([
  ...errors,
  "Another validation error text"
]);
```

Comment: it doesnt work. I will post the console output

Comment: It's very hard to understand your console output, because it does not correspond to the code you've posted. It's weird that the logs starts with `errors` state including 3 instances of "No new error" strings. It looks like there's something else you did not include in your post that might cause additional bugs.